# How to share user generated content to Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-share

Usually I use Firebase Dynamic link to let user share content from my app via SMS or Email.So I generate a link like below for them to do that.

> https://appcode.app.goo.gl/?link=http://www.example.com/?post_id=112&apn=com.example.com

Usually after user clicked this link will lead to my app's `SinglePostActivity.java` and show `Post` with **Id**=112.My Content have text,image as well.

But when I integrate Facebook share button with the same link,it not redirect to my apps as usual,but it just a broken link,and Facebook also blocked the link.

Here is how I integrate with Facebook share

```
facebookShare = (Button)findViewById(R.id.facebookShare); 

facebookShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                    ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(generateDeepLink(postId)))//this will generate the link above
                            .build();

                    shareDialog.show(content);
                }
            }
        });
```

So my question is,how to let user share the content,and lead user to to my `SinglePostActivity.java` when they click the link?And I don't have website version for my app currently.

Comment: Suggest you start by applying proper URL-encoding to your URL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mine is android only too.  You're basically just adding a custom (protocol) scheme to your manifest that handles when the link of that webpage gets clicked.  Something like, `myapp://app.mycompany.com/123`.  Facebook native app will then forward to your app I believe.

[Here's more info about app links](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content)

The issue I have with this is that the data cannot (easily) be dynamic.  It has to exist beforehand - or - you have to dynamically build the head tag that points to the data?  I'm not sure if the head tag can be dynamic....  That's what I'm struggling with at the moment.